# Pentaho Data Integration User Defined Java Class

Tags: java, jar, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I create simple java class and export it to jar:

```
package test;
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Jar file add to lib folder in Pentaho (there are many jar files)
Next step I want to use my class in Pentaho Data Integration so I created User Defined Java Class:

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    test.Test t = new test.Test();
    return true;
}
```

When I click Test class I get the following information:

> Line 3, Column 12: Class "test.Test" not found

So I have a question: Where is the mistake and why is the class not found?

Comment: Maybe `import test;` at the top of the file?

Comment: See that I use full name class with package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try checking the **launcher.property** file inside the `/design-tools/data-integration/launcher` folder. Make sure that the classpath and the libraries are having the path of the jar defined. Since you have placed your JAR file inside the `lib` folder, look for that.

[image]

2. Restart the Spoon after editing and it would work ideally.

I have placed the code inside the `libext` folder, so i have added `:../libext` to the classpath and libraries. And below is the code snip:

[image]

In case it still throws an error, try checking the Java code again. I assume something might have gone wrong there.

Also documented the above in [here](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/using-external-jars-import-in-pentaho-data-integration/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is work. Moreover your proposition I changed permission in data-integration folder to 777.